# $\text{proj} _{u_1}v + \text{proj} _{u_2}v = \text{proj} _{U}v$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $U = $span$\{u_1,u_2\}$ , $u_1,u_2$ are orthogonal and $v$ be a vector. Does the following holds true? $$\text{proj} _{u_1}v + \text{proj} _{u_2}v = \text{proj} _{U}v$$

Comment: Are you going to delete the question as soon as you get the answer?

Comment: Right ... I got news for you, this question is even less interesting than the previous one.

Comment: Please study [our guide to new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) and improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. It is enough to verify that the equation holds for $v$ of the form $au_1+bu_2$ and the equation holds for this $v$ because $proj_{u_1} (au_1+bu_2)=au_1$ (in view of orthogonality) and $proj_{u_2} (au_1+bu_2)=bu_2$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.  For instance, take
$$
v = u_1 = (1,0), \quad u_2 = (1,1)
$$

Comment: You forgot the hypothesis that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are orthogonal.

Comment: @Kavi This assumption had not been written into the question when I answered it 8 hours ago